# How do I Remove 'Non-existent' folder

Tags: files-folders

I downloaded and unzipped a music album to my D: drive. Then I went to delete it using Explorer and it appeared to do the job.

However, the folder still exists, so I kept trying to delete it without success.
The folder name is "Zac Brown Band - Greatest Hits So Far..." and it appears to be empty.

If I try to delete it reports 'Could Not Find This Item"

I cannot rename it I get the same report.

If I try to open it, it reports it as being unavailable.

I opened CMD as admin and the folder is shown as a dir, but I cannot open it and CMD reports "The system cannot find the path specified." (I used CD "Zac Brown Band - Greatest Hits So Far...")

I even emptied the rest of the Downloads folder and tried ERASE * without success.

If I try rmdir it tells me that the folder is not empty, but I cannot get into the folder to see.

I tried DIR /x, but the name is the same.

I tried a few 'unlock' programs, but they all come to the same conclusion, the folder doesn't exist.

But it is showing on Explorer and in command line.

Advice please.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing paths in the "standard" way (through Win32), Windows always trims trailing periods from the path for historical reasons. So whenever you ask to open `foo...` the OS actually tries to open `foo` instead, which indeed doesn't exist.

You can bypass that by specifying the "NT path" with `\\?\` prefix, which is most likely how the archiver created the directory in the first place:

```
rmdir "\\?\D:\Downloads\Zac Brown Band - Greatest Hits So Far..."
```

*(Many file managers and archivers use this method because it allows bypassing the 256-character length limit, and they aren't always careful to avoid creating "bad" filenames.)*

It also won't happen if you explicitly specify which data stream to delete: (this works in Cmd, but not in PowerShell)

```
rmdir "Greatest Hits So Far...::$INDEX_ALLOCATION"
```

*(The syntax is `file_name:stream_name[:stream_type]`. All files hold their primary data in a nameless stream of type $DATA, and directories have several streams but the most important one is of type $INDEX_ALLOCATION.)*

Comment: Thanks for that useful information. It sounds as though it will work. Unfortunately, I have reformatted the drive (after moving all other files) so I cannot test your code. Obviously my "hammer to crack a nut" approach did work, I am now sorry I did not wait a little bit longer.

Comment: Oh, you absolute gem. THANK YOU - I had the same problem as OP, and nothing else (rmdir, del, powershell, taking ownership, safe mode, chkdsk) worked. Adding ":$INDEX_ALLOCATION" to the folder path finally deleted the folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some corruption in the filesystem. Open a Command Prompt as administrator then type `chkdsk D: /F`. This will attempt to fix problems in the filesystem.

If that fails to delete the ghost folder, try creating a new folder exactly the same name and location as the ghost folder then delete it.

EDIT: I have done some tests and have found that the Windows built-in tools can't handle names that end with a period (`.`). You can delete this folder by opening [7-Zip File Manager](https://www.7-zip.org), browse to where the folder is, select it then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. That should delete the stuck folder.

Comment: Hi, I tried that and no change. I also tried chkdsk at startup with again no change.

Comment: Try recreating then deleting the folder.

Comment: Perhaps the folder name contains strange, not printable characters. If rmdir says that the folder is not empty, it have found it. Right ? Perhaps there are hidden files in this folder.

Comment: Try `rmdir /s "Zac Brown Band - Greatest Hits So Far..."`. The `/s` switch deletes folders that aren't empty.

Comment: Thanks for those ideas. Recreating the folder removes the ... from the end and creates "Zac Brown Band - Greatest Hits So Far".

Comment: rmdir now says it cannot find the folder. rmdir /s did not find the folder.

Comment: It's something to do with the `...` on the end Windows can't handle. Whatever you used shouldn't been able to create a folder with such a name. What program did you use to unzip it?

Comment: I used Peazip, and have used it for years.